# Iterate object and list all found properties that match input

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, for-loop, for-in-loop

Im trying to solve a javascript problem I have. I have a object with lots of properties. I want to iterate over the properties to find ALL entries of the input the user does. I've written a for..in-loop but its not giving me any info.

Any ideas?

```
var numbers = {
    "Group1": "3300",
    "Group2": "1200",
    "Group3": "5000"
};

function test(){

        var input = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;

        for(var group in numbers){

             if(numbers[group] == input){
                 console.log(numbers[group])
             }
        }           
}
```

This code is logging nothing in my console. What A'm I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably your input is neither `"3300"` nor `"1200"` nor `"5000"` or you are not calling `test`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L3droy1m/  works, check the input value is what you think it is.

Comment: Learn to use the JavaScript debugger built into your browser. You can single step through your code and look at all the variables and other values at each step of the way. This is much better than just using `console.log()`. Here's a [tutorial for the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Other browsers have similar debuggers. Just add a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of your `test()` function, and it will stop in the debugger when it gets there if you have the DevTools open. Also: ***Do you ever call the `test()` function?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've created a plnkr here,

https://plnkr.co/edit/cpdipV2qxAUa4pHtdKqA?p=preview

it seems to work

```
for(var group in numbers){

             if(numbers[group] == input){
                 console.log(numbers[group])
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Object.keys(numbers).forEach((key) => {
    if (numbers[key] == input) {
        console.log(key + " " + numbers[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Object.keys is a far more reliable way to get at the properties of a given object. for..in loops can sometimes behave unexpectedly when you don't have a complete understanding of how an object works. This method is also more explicit which never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

that works with a for in loop

```
var numbers = { "Group1": "3300", "Group2": "1200", "Group3": "5000" };
var input = "3300";
for(var group in numbers)
   if(numbers[group] == input)
      console.log(group + " " + numbers[group]); // Group1 3300
```